# Como fazer uma meta description e meta keywords única, em um documento PHP que só tem 1 header pra todas as páginas

Tags: php, html

Recentemente eu aprendi como deixar um site estático um pouco dinâmico, colocando o footer e header em um único documento para todas as páginas. Mas pra cada página eu preciso de uma meta description e meta keywords diferentes. Como faço isso?

O script que eu usei:

```
<?php
function carrega_pagina(){
(isset($_GET['p'])) ? $pagina = $_GET['p'] : $pagina = 'home';
if(file_exists('page_'.$pagina.'.php')):
    require_once('page_'.$pagina.'.php');
else:
    require_once('page_home.php');
endif;
}

function gera_titulos(){
(isset($_GET['p'])) ? $pagina = $_GET['p'] : $pagina = 'home';
switch ($pagina):

    case 'contato':
        $titulo = 'Contato - BizarroNEWS';
        break;

    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade | BizarroNEWS';
        break;

    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Últimas Notícias | BizarroNEWS';
        break;

    default:
        $titulo = 'BizarroNEWS | Home';
        break;

endswitch;
return $titulo;
}
```

Documento index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('funcoes.php');
require_once('header.php');
carrega_pagina();
require_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Eu tenho 3 documentos chamados `header.php`, `index.php` e `footer.php`.

O `header.php` so tem o header da página, `footer.php` só tem o footer, e o `index.php` só tem o comando PHP que está chamando o arquivo `funcoes.php` (primeiro script que colei na pergunta), `header.php` e `footer.php`.

E tenho mais documentos chamados `page_home.php`, `page_ultimasnoticias.php`, `page_contato.php` e `page_privacidade`. Dentro deles só o conteudo da página, sem footer e sem header.

Comment: Sim, é relevante, caso contrário não teremos a menor noção do que você fez e como modificar para atender sua necessidade.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: @DiogenesSilva como a página está sendo carregada na URL? Assim? `http://127.0.0.1/pagina.php`

Comment: @JorgeMatheus Eu to usando o server Apache. O URL fica assim: http://localhost/site/?p=home, http://localhost/site/?p=contato...etc

Comment: Se você já tem essa lógica toda para mudar o título, qual a dificuldade de fazer exatamente a mesma coisa para os META? `$titulo="contato"; $keywords="formulário, fale conosco, SAC... $description="Uma linda e aconchegante página de contato, com todos os campos e botões que você espera"`

Comment: @Bacco Não é bem isso, eu não sei colocar uma META description e keywords unica para cada página, sendo que eu só tenho 1 header para todas.

Comment: Se você muda o título, está mudando o header. Basta aplicar a mesma lógica nas tags meta. (o título faz parte do header).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta aproveitar o que já tem, aliais o seu `gera_titulos` esta mais para um `get_titulos`, quero dizer, seria mais interessante se a propria função gerasse tudo, até o o HTML, e sinceramente nem tem necessidade de separar em funções, afinal só vai usar uma vez

exemplo seria algo como:

- funcoes.php (para qualquer coisa que for usar, não precisa das funções que você criou)
- init.php (vai conter o que checa as paginas e cria as variaveis)
- header.php (vai gerar o metas e title)
- footer.php (vai gerar o rodapé)

**init.php**

```
<?php

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

switch ($pagina):
    case 'contato':
        $titulo = 'Contato - BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'Fale Conosco, Localização, Endereço';
        $descricao = 'Formulário de contato, mapa e telefones';
        break;

    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade | BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'GDPR, Privacy, Privacidade, Proteção de dados';
        $descricao = 'Entenda seus direitos e como usamos seus dados';
        break;

    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Últimas Notícias | BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'News, Newsfeed, Notícias';
        $descricao = 'Saiba tudo que acontece no Bizarro';
        break;

    default:
        $titulo = 'BizarroNEWS | Home';
        $keywords = '';
        $descricao = 'Home page';
        $pagina = 'home';
endswitch;
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php
require_once 'init.php';
require_once 'funcoes.php';
require_once 'header.php';
require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php';
require_once 'footer.php';
```

---

Claro que como você vai receber tudo no index.php você poderia reduzir bem as coisas, afinal são coisas simples, não precisa destes includes todos, muita coisa poderia ser resolvida ali no index.php mesmo, por exemplo:

**index.php**

```
<?php

$pagina = empty($_GET['p']) ? 'home' : $_GET['p'];

switch ($pagina):
    case 'contato':
        $titulo = 'Contato - BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'Fale Conosco, Localização, Endereço';
        $descricao = 'Formulário de contato, mapa e telefones';
        break;

    case 'privacidade':
        $titulo = 'Privacidade | BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'GDPR, Privacy, Privacidade, Proteção de dados';
        $descricao = 'Entenda seus direitos e como usamos seus dados';
        break;

    case 'ultimasnoticias':
        $titulo = 'Últimas Notícias | BizarroNEWS';
        $keywords = 'News, Newsfeed, Notícias';
        $descricao = 'Saiba tudo que acontece no Bizarro';
        break;

    default:
        $titulo = 'BizarroNEWS | Home';
        $keywords = '';
        $descricao = 'Home page';
        $pagina = 'home';
endswitch;
?><html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $titulo; ?></title>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $keywords; ?>">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $descricao; ?>">
</head>
<body>

<?php require_once 'page_' . $pagina . '.php'; ?>

<footer>Rodapé</footer>
</body>
</header>
```

Comment: O problema é que eu não sei como colocar uma description e keyword unica para cada página, sendo que eu só tenho 1 header pra todas as páginas. Eu preciso saber como colocar essas META Tags em cada página. E eu vou ter que fazer isso sempre, sendo que por dia eu crio umas 2 páginas para o meu site de noticias. Obs: A variavel no documento header.php deveria se chamar $titulo, assim como está no init.php.

Comment: @Bacco Eu vi, eu consigo alterar o valor delas usando as variaveis, mas eu não sei como colocar um comando que gere essas meta tags únicamente para cada página. Eu sou do tipo que aprende fazendo, e ainda não aprende a fazer esse tipo de coisa, me desculpe.

Comment: Show! +1 pela elaboração/criação dos `includes`

Comment: @DiogenesSilva editei a resposta do colega Guilherme acima, veja se ficou mais fácil de entender agora a solução

Comment: @Bacco Entendi sim. Só tenho 2 perguntas, eu não sei se existe algum tipo de regra sobre as páginas que estão com o nome "page_" na frente de cada uma (coloquei esse nome pq me disseram), 1° eu tenho que renomear todos os meus documentos e colocar o "page_" na frente deles? 2° Tem algum problema eu colocar um titulo de uns 100 characteres no case que está dentro do switch?

Comment: O que está no case tem que ser igual o que está no `p=` do link usado. Tem que ser identico. Essas outras duvidas já seriam separadas do que foi perguntado (e respondido).

Comment: @DiogenesSilva  1. Não existe regras, `page_` é uma ideia, poderia ser uma pasta também, ou poderia ser qualquer outro método de organização mirabolante 2. Para o PHP não tem, mas no google buscador o titulo tem limite de 70 caracteres (se eu não me engano), então para exibir nos buscadores não adiantar por algo muito grande, o descripition tem limite de 160 se eu não me engano para o Google.

Comment: @DiogenesSilva você teria que ver no seu fonte original como estão os links `<a href="caminho?p=nomedapagina">` e usar o que estiver depois do ´p=` no case, mas isso só você olhando no seu código fonte. Não teriamos como deduzir o que é mais certo no seu caso, só você olhando o fonte mesmo

Comment: @Bacco Certo, acho que aqui já estou mudando o foco da pergunta que fiz inicialmente, se for o caso eu crio outra pergunta. Obrigado!

Comment: @DiogenesSilva lembrando ainda que se for coisa muito vaga, tem o chat da rede, acho que seus pontos já dão acesso

Answer (score 0):

**Atenção: O exemplo só servirá para o case citado pelo autor** .

Você pode pegar a página atual que está sendo usada através do parâmetro `p` usando `$_GET['p']` e fazer a verificação de acordo com a necessidade, gravando assim o valor em uma `constante` para poder ser usado nas páginas que conterá o `meta`.

Na sua página index.php:

```
  <?php         
    $str = $_GET['p'];  
    switch($str) {
        case 'teste':
        define('TITULO',' o titulo é teste');
        break;
        case 'home':
        define('TITULO',' o titulo é home');
        break;
        default:
        define('TITULO','nenhum titulo');
        break;
    }

    include "teste2.php";
 ?>
```

No seu arquivo que contém as `metas tags`, (no meu caso, é o arquivo `teste2.php`) ficaria assim:

```
<?php 

    echo "Aqui está o titulo em outra pagina:: ".TITULO;
 ?>

 <meta name="description" content="<?php echo TITULO?>" />
```

**OBSERVAÇÕES:**

1 - Usei um exemplo de URL citado pelo autor: http://127.0.0.1/site/?p=home

2- Note que importei o arquivo (`include "teste2.php"`) no final da página `index.php`.

3- Use o `DevTools` do navegador para ver como a tag `meta` ficou, no meu caso está assim:  http://prntscr.com/kni7vc

Comment: Eu comecei a estudar PHP bem recentemente, como exatamente eu faço isso?

Comment: @DiogenesSilva reeditei a resposta.